# CharacterBody3D gravity isn't working, and player won't touch the floor

Tags: physics, 3d, path-finding, godot-4

I'm trying to create an isometric game with *Diablo-like* control, but gravity isn't working. The CharacterBody3D won't touch the floor, the print(is_on_floor()) always results false.

Here's my code for **PlayerCapsule.gd**

```
extends ActorPlayable3D
class_name PlayerCapsule


var navigationAgent3D

func _ready():
    navigationAgent3D = get_node(navigationAgent)


func _physics_process(delta):
    velocity.y -= gravity * delta
    if navigationAgent3D.is_navigation_finished():
        return
    
    var movement_delta = speed * delta
    var next_path_position: Vector3 = navigationAgent3D.get_next_path_position()
    var current_agent_position: Vector3 = global_position
    var new_velocity: Vector3 = (next_path_position - current_agent_position).normalized() * speed
    if navigationAgent3D.avoidance_enabled:
        navigationAgent3D.set_velocity(new_velocity)
    else:
        _on_navigation_agent_3d_velocity_computed(new_velocity)

func setNavigationAgentToLocation(pos: Vector3):
    navigationAgent3D.set_target_position(pos)


func _on_navigation_agent_3d_velocity_computed(safe_velocity):
    velocity = safe_velocity
    print(safe_velocity)
    print(is_on_floor())
    move_and_slide()
```

And here's the **ActorPlayable3D.gd**

```
extends CharacterBody3D
class_name ActorPlayable3D

@export var speed: float = 5.0
@export var navigationAgent: NodePath

var gravity = ProjectSettings.get_setting("physics/3d/default_gravity")

class Navigation:
    func setNavigationAgent(node: NavigationAgent3D) -> void:
        pass
```

And here's the image result of the output, and playable scene:

[image]

[image]

How can I fix the gravity and make the player touch the floor?

Answer (score 0):

For `is_on_floor` to return true, the body needs to be moving (e.g. `move_and_slide` was called) against a floor (e.g. with gravity applied).

But the next position according to navigation is not below the ground, so the new velocity you compute is not going to downwards. And thus, the body would not be falling.

Ergo, you need to apply gravity after navigation.

A lesser issue is that the result of `is_on_floor` is updated when you call `move_and_slide`, so if you check it before `move_and_slide` you are getting the result from last physics frame. Which might or might not be what you want.

Comment: Problem has been solved in this [Link](https://ask.godotengine.org/155081/gravity-not-working-and-characterbody3d-wont-touching-floor)

Comment: I requested a mirror in case somebody wants to look at it, and for whatever reason the site is down: [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20230721222803/https://ask.godotengine.org/155081/gravity-not-working-and-characterbody3d-wont-touching-floor).